# Remove/delete child only

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Python 3.5 I scrape data from the internet and using Pyrebase 3.0.27 library to perform a CRUD operation for my Firebase database. The update and get method of Pyrebase works well except the remove.

I have a Firebase structure like this

```
mycustomapp-51146
   -CebuPacific
      -db_fare
          +1
          +2
          +3
          +4
```

When executing this method:

```
self._fb_database.child('CebuPacific').child('db_fare').remove(self._fb_token)
```

This will be the result:

```
mycustomapp-51146
```

But this is the result I wish to achieve:

```
mycustomapp-51146
   -CebuPacific
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Database automatically creates nodes as they are needed, and automatically removes nodes that are no longer needed.

The code you write removes all children from the `db_fare` node. The Firebase Database automatically removes empty nodes, so this operation will also remove the `db_fare` node itself. If that nodes was the only remaining node under `CebuPacific`, then `CebuPacific` itself will also be removed.

Comment: Hi Frank, you're absolutely correct. I tried to add an additional child under CebuPacific and execute again the remove method. It works as what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks a lot, you're a life saver.

Comment: Frank, I cannot perform the upvote because it requires 15 reputations, hence I only did the check mark. Thanks once again!